# How do I delay a css animation till I have scrolled to the element in React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have built an animation similar to this and now I want to ensure that it will play only when the user has scrolled to a certain location such that the content being animated is actually visible. How do I do that inside a React App ?
I have tried reading up on the problem but most solutions either point to *jQuery* or *Animate.css* or *waypoint js*.

---

1. Is there any way to do this without using any of these ?
2. How does React and jQuery work together without causing a conflict ? (I ask because I am also using react-bootstrap and they explicitly state that they have built it from scratch to avoid using jQuery with React) Where should i even write the jQuery code ?

```css
body{
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.container{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@keyframes load{
  from {
    width: 0%
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes load{
  from {
    width: 0%
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes load{
  from {
    width: 0%
  }
}
@-o-keyframes load{
  from {
    width: 0%
  }
}

.bar{
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.bar::before{
  content:  attr(data-skill);
  background-color: #f3b0ff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  animation: load 2s 0s;
  -webkit-animation: load 2s 0s;
  -moz-animation: load 2s 0s;
  -o-animation: load 2s 0s;
}

.bar.front::before{
  background-color: #ffcc33;
}
.bar.back::before{
  background-color: #a6cfe3;
}

.bar.learning::before{
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
}
.bar.basic::before{
  width: calc(40% - 10px);
}
.bar.intermediate::before{
  width: calc(60% - 10px);
}
.bar.advanced::before{
  width: calc(80% - 10px);
}
.bar.expert::before{
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Skill Set</h1>
    <div class="bar learning" data-skill="TDD"></div>
    <div class="bar back basic" data-skill="Python"></div>
    <div class="bar back intermediate" data-skill="C#"></div>
    <div class="bar front advanced" data-skill="CSS3"></div>
    <div class="bar front expert" data-skill="HTML5"></div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can always use a library like [react-is-visible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-is-visible). This tracks the visibility of the component. You could then set a `useEffect` on the visibility variable, which could then add a class to your to-be-animated component once it becomes visible.

Extended documentation from package to suit this answer

```
import React, { useRef } from "react"
import { useIsVisible } from "react-is-visible"

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const nodeRef = useRef();
  const isVisible = useIsVisible(nodeRef);

  return (
    <div ref={nodeRef} className={`bar${isVisible ? ' animate' : ''}`}>
      {..content of div}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You will then need to edit your CSS as well

```
.bar{
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.bar::before{
  content:  attr(data-skill);
  background-color: #f3b0ff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
.bar.animate::before{
  animation: load 2s 0s;
  -webkit-animation: load 2s 0s;
  -moz-animation: load 2s 0s;
  -o-animation: load 2s 0s;
}

.bar.front::before{
  background-color: #ffcc33;
```

2. Why would you want jQuery and React to work together? React should be able to achieve what you want to achieve with jQuery!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26147736)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The first part answers the question, so it is an answer.

Comment: In its current state that part is just a link to a library. If you want to make this an answer, then demonstrate a solution.

Comment: It's also adding a rough outline to how to use the library in this example.

Comment: We really need to handhold everyone in our answers?

Comment: You are not just answering for the sake of the person asking the question, but also for people arriving here through a search engine. More details is usually better, and more likely to attract upvotes. On the other hand answers that just link to a solution or just comment on the question are not considered answers.

Comment: Hi I had a look at the node package. It also uses the intersection observer API as told by another answer below. However I do not quiet understand how to use it from the documentation provided on there. Could you elaborate further ? 
For eg: Say i have a functional component with no state and just plain jsx. How would I check if this component is visible using that package ?

Comment: In My case i just have plain jsx wrapped inside a react fragment which i am returning from a functional component. Something like function MYCOMPONENT(props) { return(<>) }; export default MYCOMPONENT. The html(jsx) is inside the <> fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with vanilla JavaScript. Use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect whenever your element has entered the viewport. When it has, add a class to element that you want to animate.

See the example below:

```js
const observerCallback = (entries, observer) => {
  for (const { target, isIntersecting } of entries) {
    if (isIntersecting) {
      target.classList.add('animate');
      observer.unobserve(target);
    }
  }
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: [0]
});

const trigger = document.querySelector('.js-animation-trigger');

observer.observe(trigger);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1000px auto 0;
}

@keyframes load {
  from {
    width: 0%
  }
}

.bar {
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.bar::before {
  content: attr(data-skill);
  background-color: #f3b0ff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  animation: load 2s 0s paused;
}

/* Start playing */
.animate .bar::before {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.bar.front::before {
  background-color: #ffcc33;
}

.bar.back::before {
  background-color: #a6cfe3;
}

.bar.learning::before {
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
}

.bar.basic::before {
  width: calc(40% - 10px);
}

.bar.intermediate::before {
  width: calc(60% - 10px);
}

.bar.advanced::before {
  width: calc(80% - 10px);
}

.bar.expert::before {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="js-animation-trigger">
    <h1>Skill Set</h1>
    <div class="bar learning" data-skill="TDD"></div>
    <div class="bar back basic" data-skill="Python"></div>
    <div class="bar back intermediate" data-skill="C#"></div>
    <div class="bar front advanced" data-skill="CSS3"></div>
    <div class="bar front expert" data-skill="HTML5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see that this works. Where do I write this javascript code while working with React ?

Comment: in your component obviously

Answer (score 1):

As Emiel mentioned, you can use the Intersection Observer API, and I personally recommend it's React implementation: [react-intersection-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer).

I guess all you need is packed in one hook [useInView](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer#useinview-hook):

```
const { ref, inView } = useInView({
 triggerOnce: true,
});
```

Where "ref" - is ref, which you set to your component, I believe in your case code will be similar to this:

```
    import React, { useRef } from "react"
    import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';

    const SomeComponent = () => {
      const { ref, inView } = useInView({
        triggerOnce: true,
      });

      return (
      <div ref={ref} className="container">
        {inView && ..content of div}
      </div>
      );
    }
```

This way animated content will be rendered only if it is in the view, and will trigger once thanks to optional prop "triggerOnce".